# I want to change the game activity in a Discord Server for my bot, how do I do that?

Tags: c#, discord

So this is my code program.cs

```
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandService _commands;
    private IServiceProvider _services;
    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();

        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        string botToken = "";

        _client.Log += Log;
        _client.UserJoined += AnnounceUserJoined;
        _client.UserIsTyping += UserIsTyping;

        await RegisterCommandsAsync();

        await _client.LoginAsync(Discord.TokenType.Bot, botToken);

        await _client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);


    }

    private async Task AnnounceUserJoined(SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        var guild = user.Guild;
        var channel = guild.DefaultChannel;
        await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Welcome, {user.Mention} nice to see you! (≧∇≦)ﾉ");
    }
    private async Task UserIsTyping(SocketUser u, ISocketMessageChannel m)
    {
        int random = new Random().Next(0, 10);
        string username = u.Username;
        if (random == 5)
        {
            await m.SendMessageAsync("*Watcha typin " + username + "? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)*");
        }

    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);

        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }

    public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
    {
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;

        await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;

        if (message is null || message.Author.IsBot) return;

        int argPos = 0;

        if (message.HasStringPrefix("$", ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))
        {
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

            var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);

            if (!result.IsSuccess)
                Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
        }
    }

}
```

}

I tried many things but didn't get it.

All other commands work just fine except for this one.

It would be really cool when there would stand "playing a Game" in the game activity.
I use it with the Discord.NET.
Is it even possible to show it with Discord.NET?

This is my first question so thank you for every answer. ;)

I am using windows on c# vs 2020

please help
thank you :)

Comment: Use `Context.Client.SetGameAsync()`

Comment: This Error appears: **CS0103 C# The name "Context" is not available in the current context.**

Comment: Where are you trying to set the game? That works if it's in the context of a command.

Comment: I got it thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `await Context.Client.SetGameAsync("");` to change your game activity. Use this in the startup of your bot or in a command where either the `Context` or `client` (your bot client) is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This would be under your `DiscordSocketClient`, so your `_client` here. Use `_client.SetGameAsync()`.